# Is it possible to copy code from one AWS Lambda function to another without downloading it first?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I'm currently working on building the deployer for our AWS Lambda functions.

Since AWS versions all share a configuration, this requires having multiple functions (foo_prod, foo_staging, foo_whatever) that are the various versions of our code instead of using aliases like I *want* to do.

So my question is:

1) Whether or not there's a sane way to re-deploy code.  (IE: Staging to Prod) without downloading it to my desktop first and then re-uploading.

2) Whether or not I'm wrong about that shared configuration bit or whether it's possible to tell under which alias the function is running in the actual Lambda such that I can create multiple environment variables for each environment.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/)?  There are several examples out there.  You can also define environment variables in the serverless.yml file.

Comment: The problem is that we don't want this to be automatic, we'd like deploys (at least to staging and Prod) to be manual (and then scripted elsewhere) so we have perfect control over all our Lambda functions.

Comment: @ShaheinMoussavi, make a quick read of Serverless help and didn't find how it helps us to migrate functions between regions or accounts? Could you, please, elaborate it more or give proper help chapter?

Comment: @Suncatcher, the OP didn't ask about migrating functions between regions and accounts.  I think that should be its own question (there's more to it than I can fit here), but it can be done. The simplest way I know of for separate accounts would be configuring separate AWS profiles on your local machine and using the `--aws-profile` flag (example here - https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#using-the-aws-profile-option). 
Regions can be set directly with the `--region` flag. (example -https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials#tips)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can deploy lambda functions in a lot of different ways that don't involve downloading and re-uploading code. If you use something like SAM (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-use-app-spec.html) you can just point to an S3 bucket that holds your code and build functions from that. You can also hook CloudFormation up to git repository like Github or AWS CodeCommit and have it automatically update your functions when you push commits to the repository. And there are other systems like Severless (https://serverless.com) that can abstract and automate deploys in repeatable and manageable ways.

The Lambda's version is available in the context object. You should be able to tell which alias is called by looking at the ARN. ARNs have the alias as a suffix such as:

```
arn:aws:lambda:aws-region:acct-id:function:helloworld:PROD
```

Info here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html

Comment: [https://sigma.slappforge.com](https://sigma.slappforge.com) is also a great online IDE to manage your lambda related projects.

Comment: And can I do this with Eclipse AWS Toolkit? To import function from one account and deploy to another? I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647831/import-python-lambda-function-into-eclipse-aws-toolkit) a long ago, but nobody had any idea.

Comment: There is a lot more to Lambda than the script being executed. A real solution would use the boto3 library and extract both the code and the settings (triggers, role, network, memory, timeout, env vars, test events, etc.) and allow you to create a new function with the exact same values (or optionally modified values, which are all just JSON). it would be like Terraform but without the preplanning.

Comment: As @BrunoBronosky mentions, the idea of copying a lambda function is much more than the code. Sometimes for replication of a, say production environment, you want it to be just-as, not only code like.

Comment: @Daniel if you looked at the first link posted in the answer, you would see that this is precisely what I am advising. Using something like SAM allows you to set all these options while still pointing to a single code artifact. You can also use any number of IaC tools like serverless (as mentioned above) or Terraform. I don't think there's anywhere in this answer where I suggested you *only* copy the code.