# Import Python Lambda function into Eclipse AWS Toolkit

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, aws-lambda

How to import Lambda function to AWS Toolkit for Eclipse?

I exported my function from AWS Console to YAML and ZIP-packages, how can I use that stuff with Eclipse? There is [number of tutorials](https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-develop-lambda-applications-aws-toolkit-eclipse/) how to create function from scratch but what if I want to deploy existing function?

Comment: I'd like to see this in general - all of the documentation seems to be about creating a new function using the IDE. I'd like to see a walkthrough about opening an existing function that's already in Lambda and update/editing it with an IDE.